# apache reverse proxy header check

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

Is it possible to check (in the reverse proxy!) on an concrete header-value inside a location?

The request should be routed to the backend, **only** if there is an header-item "secret" with the value="3J185AydV4bq27wG6JLEZYhQa9MZ0W". And just for this location-entry.

```
<Location "/api/execute">
    ProxyPass http://192.168.10.1:99/api/execute
    ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.10.1:99/api/execute

</Location>
```